# Why am I getting this error in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. When I run react-native run-android I get this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Stay Hungry\app developement\Aarogya\node_modules\react-native-share\android\build.gradle' line: 53

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-share'.
> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7 mins 24.686 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I traced the path to the error location and my build.gradle is below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 27)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '27.0.3')


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 16)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('targetSdkVersion', 27)

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly "com.facebook.react:react-native:${safeExtGet('reactNativeVersion', '+')}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '27.1.0')}"
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong here. I have not even started writing code in app.js yet. I am using a physical device to run the code with an adb device.

Comment: Try to replace compileOnly to implementation

Comment: You mean instead of compileOnly I should write implementation ? (its already written in next line)

Comment: I think you need to check [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/327)

Comment: What `distributionURL` do you have in PROJECT_PATH/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is from the library react-native-share.

Did you follow the instructions to installing it right?

Comment: I first upgraded the react native version, than I used npm install command, than I used react-native-link and finnaly run-android

Comment: Okay, don't really trust react native link in the future cause almost always you'll have problems with that, specially if you have more than 1 library linked.
I recommend you to follow the manual installation

Comment: You should check The manifest, settings.gradle, and the two build.gradle files.
I can't send you my config for firebase if you can't solve it later